# Haproxy http response timeout check

Tags: time, response, haproxy

We use haproxy as http load balancer. Sometimes one of our servers stop responding while accepting http connection requests. So stats page displays servers as green "accessible" but our nagios server says CRITICAL - Socket timeout after 20 seconds" and that server is not responding actually.

How to tell haproxy to check page response time and if it takes longer than timeout then tag it as DOWN.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not specify what kind of health check you are running, I can only direct you to the manual that explains all kinds.

https://www.haproxy.com/doc/aloha/7.0/haproxy/healthchecks.html

Concentrate on setting the correct Timeout for your health check.

Comment: We use http health check, sample backend line<br>

server 224.ubs 193.***.***.***:80 check port 80 id 224.ubs cookie 224.ubs